# Access LAN files from DMZ

Tags: security, file-transfer, dmz

We have an application that stores files on a file server in our LAN.  Now, they want a web application to make the files available on our public web server (in the DMZ).  What's the best method for accessing those files from the web application?

The options I've considered are:

1. FTP from the DMZ to the LAN server. (cheapest and easiest)
2. A second file server in the DMZ and the files are pushed to it from the LAN.  (Better performance and security, but also more money)

Comment: Why did this get a close vote?  While it certainly is related to sys admin as well, it pertains to the most efficient and secure way to access files from an application.

Answer (score 1):

Configure a reverse proxy in the DMZ which will talk to the web servers (web application) in the backend internal network. This should solve your problem as the real web application will be separated from the external world. Use firewalls, SSL, Client autentication for better security.

Answer (score -1):

just avoid Demilitarized Zones (DMZ) all together! They're the "bluetooth" of networks